# Are implicitly unwrapped optionals truly optionals?

Tags: swift, option-type, inout

In Swift 4.0, the following code doesn't compile:

```
var str: String!
func someFunc(_ s: inout String?) {}
someFunc(&str)
```

Now I imagine that `str` is of type `String?` in actuality, and the Swift compiler seems to agree:

> Cannot pass immutable value of type 'String?' as inout argument

I can fix this by either changing the the variable to type `String?` or the function parameters to `(_ s: inout String!)` but I don't understand why I have to. Swift already seems to agree that `var str : String!` is "of type 'String?'" — so why won't it let me pass it in here?

Is there another option I can use to keep my variable implicitly unwrapped, but still pass it to a function that modifies an optional?

<s>I tried `someFunc(&(str?))` and that just makes things weirder — **then** Swift complains:</s>

> Cannot pass immutable value of type 'String!' as inout argument".

So `str` is a `String?` but can't be passed as a `String?`, while `str?` is a `String!`?!

That code was actually:

```
var str: String!
func someFunc(_ x: inout String!) {}
someFunc(&(str?))
```

So maybe Swift is mistakenly saying the type of the parameter, rather than the value passed, in its error message…or something?

Comment: Why would you use an unsafe construct like an IUO?

Comment: Probably an artifact of how IUO is implemented in the compiler.

Comment: I agree your first example should compile under the rules set out by [SE-0054](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md), that fact that it doesn't is a bug. It does compile using the latest 4.1 snapshot though, so looks like it has already been fixed.

Comment: @Hamish Thanks — the example in this question did get fixed after upgrading to Xcode 9.3. But it turns out the actual function call wasn't an `inout` but rather an `UnsafeMutablePointer` which is apparently still broken…? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49928472/why-cant-i-pass-an-implicitly-unwrapped-optional-as-an-unsafemutablepointer for updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug in the swift compiler](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3512). [Hamish says in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48814508/are-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals-truly-optionals#comment84633455_48814508) this is fixed in a Swift 4.1 snapshot, so it may be fixed in the next Xcode release (9.3).

You can work around this by getting rid of the implicitly-unwrapped optional (IUO), which should be avoided anyway. Depending on why it's currently an IUO, either:

```
var str: String?
func someFunc(_ x: inout String?) {}
someFunc(&str)
```

or

```
var tmp: String?
func someFunc(_ x: inout String?) {}
someFunc(&tmp)
let str = tmp!
```

I strongly recommend the first, avoid force-unwrapping unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thanks! In my case I wanted an IUO because its optionality was really just an artifact of a lower-level API I was using. Something ± like `var str : CFString!; let r = LowLevelGetter(&str); assert(r == noErr); NSLog("\(str)")` where, so long as there wasn't an error, the value is never `nil` once it is fetched.