# swift 4 extensions Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: 'self' is immutable" error message

Tags: swift, core-data, extension-methods

I created as simple extension to UIViewController, but when I call the method inside, even applying inout keyword I got  "Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: 'self' is immutable" error message. How could resolve it?

in my VC I have this var

```
var asyncComicEntityArray : [NSManagedObject]! = []
```

in my button I implemented extension this way

```
searchIfOwnedInExtension(asynchArrayToUse: &asyncComicEntityArray, showWhereOwnedIs: true)
```

and here is the extension in a separate swift file

```
EXTENSION 
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData




extension UIViewController {



    //needs a     var asyncComicEntityArray : [NSManagedObject]! = []

    func searchIfOwnedInExtension(asynchArrayToUse: inout [NSManagedObject], showWhereOwnedIs: Bool) {

        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return}
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext



        let comicFetch : NSFetchRequest<Comic> = Comic.fetchRequest()
        let predicateForRequest = NSPredicate(format: "inCollection == %@", NSNumber(booleanLiteral: showWhereOwnedIs))
        comicFetch.predicate = predicateForRequest


        do {
            asynchArrayToUse = try managedContext.fetch(comicFetch)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Fetch error: \(error) description: \(error.userInfo)")
        }

        guard asynchArrayToUse != nil else {return}
        for comic in asynchArrayToUse {
            var comicTouse = Comic()
            comicTouse = comic as! Comic
            print("comic title: \(comicTouse.comicTitle!), is it in collection? : \(comicTouse.inCollection)")
        }



    }





}
```

Comment: Try this `private static var asyncComicEntityArray : [NSManagedObject]! = []` , But do not prefer doing this better. Define the variable in class UIVIewController then call this in extension

Comment: Not related but why is `asyncComicEntityArray` implicit unwrapped optional, although it's initialized as non-optional? Don't do that. The  line `guard asynchArrayToUse` will be never evaluated to `false` anyway.

Comment: Avoid `inout`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49928472/why-cant-i-pass-an-implicitly-unwrapped-optional-as-an-unsafemutablepointer – you cannot pass an IUO as inout expression.